# Keep Blowing out 2STN1550 Transistor

Tags: transistors, 555, npn, monostable

I'm (Trying) to build a trigger timer for an air cannon to launch ham radio antennas. This is an attempt to only allow the valve to stay open by a consistent interval to get max distance without wasting air and hopefully getting multiple launches out of a tank of air.

For some reason I keep blowing the 2STN1550 NPN Transistor.
You'll see in the design that there is a voltage regulator that knocks down the 12V to 5V for the 555 timer (monostable multivibrator) and to feed the 2STN1550 transistor for a period of time set by the resistor/cap combo on the 555 timer. I've cut this circuit board and it seems ok, but after one launch I fried another 2STN1550. For the life of me I can't figure out why. Maybe someone else with more experience will have an explanation.

NOTE: the Flyback Diode is shown backward from the way I have it in reality. the valve is a sprinkler valve actuated by a solenoid that came with a 1" inline Orbit sprinkler valve.

Here is a simplified version of the part of my circuit that I'm concerned about.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKgqE4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Where's the transistor in your schematic and what is the load it is driving? What are the electrical characteristics of the load? Is there a data sheet? A data sheet link to the transistor is also useful.

Comment: It's the 4 pin device on the far right of the schematic. 
the load is an inductor that pulls about 0.5A when charged at 12V. it's the one that came with the sprinkler valve and I don't have specs on it.

Comment: @StevenLutz Ok so if I understand this, you obtain the 12V from J3 and 12V unregulated is used to drive the coil? I would then guess that the flyback isn't working as intended and the energy back from the coil is what kills the bjt. Rather than having the flyback diode as in the schematic, try to tie its cathode to ground. Also, I'm not sure if a tvs is suitable as flyback, maybe someone else can answer that.

Comment: To start, there is no capacitor on either the input or output of the 341. Second, I don't see where you are connecting to power supply ground. Or are you doing that at the switch input? Your "flyback diode" is actually a TVS. Why not use one at the 555 power?

Comment: @Lundin yes it's unregulated 12V to drive the coil. Thanks for your input on the Flyback resistor, I'll look into that.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I can add capacitors for the regulator but I really don't think that's the issue. The supply is grounded right next to the regulator. 
I wasn't aware that the Diode is actually a TVS, I had it from another application and thought it was sufficient. What would moving it to the 555 power accomplish?

Comment: Probably blowing due to exceeding SOA for VI product.  Why not use a power diode to reduce SOA stress during switching?  These are not meant to be "hammer drivers" as they were once called.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist can you elaborate on what SOA and VI are?

Comment: Safe Operating Area is where V*I product is rapidly derated vs time due to junction thermal time constant being so fast to damage.  It is not even spec'd in datasheet, but proper ones will and you must measure to find out or else do as I said.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I'll try a different diode. Thank you.

Comment: It be rated for more than applied current, but you can try 1N400x

Comment: @Tony thank you. I was just looking at a 1N4007. I'll get some on order.

Comment: I suggest editing your question and removing first paragraph. It seems your explanation of the device purpose confuses people, so they vote to close this as "unclear", even though the actual question is quite straightforward.

Comment: @StevenLutz - Please clarify something: Your original text said (and still does) "*the Flyback Diode is shown backward from the way I have it in reality*". However, the polarity of the diode *changed* between versions of the schematic, yet the text remained the same! Surely the text cannot be correct for *both* versions of your schematic? If the text was correct for the initial (Eagle) schematic, then it seems to be wrong for the later (CircuitLab) schematic, where the diode is already reversed. So, please edit your question to clarify whether that text applies to *both* schematics.

Answer (score 2):

> the Flyback Diode is shown backward from the way I have it in reality

... which makes it a shunt. No wonder you keep blowing a transistor, you basically short-circuit it to 12V.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately this answer may be wrong :-( Look at the question's [edit history](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/389935/revisions). Note that rev 1 has a *different* (Eagle) schematic, but the same text you quoted. That Eagle schematic had the diode's *anode* connected to the power rail, and the text said (as it still does) that the diode was reversed in reality. Later *the schematic was changed* to the CircuitLab one and now the diode's *cathode* connects to the power rail, yet the text was unchanged. Likely the old text you quote wasn't updated when the schematic changed. :-(

Comment: It never occurred to me to look at the edit history. Well, the answer is correct per current state of the question. I see in your comment you've asked OP to clarify. I'll keep an eye on the thread and if this was indeed obsolete description I'll remove the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.